# Oracle Java Runtime doens't appear

Tags: java, troubleshooting, oracle

[image: Oracle JDK doesn't appear]

I had installed originally Oracle JDK 7 update 4, with update-alternatives installation instruction and the JDK became manual mode (3). OpenJDK 7 in auto mode (O).

When I will run/install .jar file Oracle Java Runtime doens't appear. How should I do to fix it?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bring `Oracle JDK` to that menu then you have to create a `.desktop` file for Oracle JDK under `/usr/share/applications` if it is not already there. What about clicking `Show other application` button to see available application? If the Oracle JDK is not there then follow these steps:

1. `sudo gedit` to open gedit as super-user
2. write

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Oracle JDK
   Exec=path to Oracle's java here -jar
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=openjdk-6
   MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
   NoDisplay=true
   ```

   then save the file as `/usr/share/applications/OracleJDK.desktop`
3. `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/OracleJDK.desktop` to make the `.desktop` file executable
4. `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/bamf.index` and add the line `OracleJDK.desktop path to Oracle's java here -jar` to the end and save.
5. open the file `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` as super-user(`sudo gedit`) and add change the line `application/java-archive=openjdk-xxx.desktop;` to `application/java-archive=openjdk-xxx.desktop;OracleJDK.desktop;` i.e. just add your newly created desktop entry to mime-cache.
6. Now you should find `Oracle JDK` entry under the applications menu if you click view other applications

Comment: great thanks.. what does "-jar" mean for?

and for the path.. applying /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/java, right?

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Oracle JDK
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/bin/java -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-6
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true

why doesn't it work?

Comment: `-jar` is the argument to `java` if you want to interpret/execute `.jar` files instead of a `.class` file. And for the `.desktop` file, make sure there is no space after the `[Desktop Entry]` line or it won't work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add step 4 and 5. perform that too.

Comment: thanks... but it has not worked yet

in step 3 i writed it into .desktop and put into usr/share/applications

[Desktop Entry]
Name=Oracle Java Runtime 7
Name[fi]=Oracle Java Runtime 7
Comment=Oracle Java Runtime 7
Comment[fi]=Oracle Java Runtime 7
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/bin/java -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-7
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=true

Comment: in step 4

i added below the JDK

openjdk-7-java.desktop cautious-launcher %f /usr/bin/java -jar
openjdk-7-policytool.desktop /usr/bin/policytool
oracle-java_runtime-7.desktop /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/bin/java

in steps 5 i added

application/java-archive=openjdk-7-java.desktop;oracle-java-runtime-7.desktop

what's my wrong?

Comment: a few things from your last comment, `application/java-archive=openjdk-7-java.desktop;oracle-java-runtime-7.desktop;`(don't forget the semi-colon)  and `oracle-java_runtime-7.desktop /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/bin/java` **-jar**

Comment: the `mimeinfo.txt` is the key, it should bring the option in the right click menu. If you want to Oracle's JDK open `.jar` files by default then edit the file `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`

Comment: thank you for your help. but it's not change anything. i think all jruntime can't execute jar files via GUI mode.

Comment: Still no menu? I think the JRE has nothing to do with the menu.Because even if I give an imaginary path to JRE for the `.desktop` file, it shows up in right click menu. [Take a look in this picture(please zoom)](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/B4k725r7TRtL5PcTgywVuLg8MPTz6mpRsJRtwY9seYo?feat=directlink)

Answer (score 1):

Samik's answer is great but remove the `NoDisplay` command which hides the app in `Comice OS 4`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Oracle JDK
Exec=path to Oracle's java here -jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=openjdk-6
MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
NoDisplay=false
```

Answer (score 0):

i have searched the information about this case. Actually **Oracle JRE** runs automatically when jar files or jar files included are executed. It doesn't support interaction like this.

if jar files can't be executed, you seems not to be installed correctly.

Sorry if I'm wrong. That's all i found. If there's someone who know more, please add answer.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer is not sufficient enough

you also need to update mime list as

open file in editor

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

then replace this

```
application/x-java-archive=file-roller.desktop;
```

to

```
application/x-java-archive=OracleJDK.desktop;
```

This will resolve the problem.